# Transfer learning with ImageDataGenerator preprocessing function and tflite on android

Tags: android, keras, tensorflow-lite, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

**Background**

I am trying to perform transfer learning with **denseNet**.
I imported the model and added a couple of layers and trained them (I did not train the whole model again).

I used **ImageDataGenerator** from Keras and used the preprocessing function associated with it to preprocess the images
`keras.applications.densenet.preprocess_input`

Training went fine!

And I converted the model to **tflite** and used the sample code provided by **tensorflow** to use the model on Android.

**Question**

How can I do the same preprocessing on images taken from the android device.
Because I tried to take images and feed them into the model directly but the performance was very bad, obviously because they were not preprocessed.

Any information about how to perform the **denseNet**'s preprocessing  function mathematically using tflite?

Any other solution will be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try either using the [TFLite Task library](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification). It doesn't support DenseNet but there are other models you can use as given [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tflite_model_maker/image_classifier). Here is the end-to-end example for [image classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/image_classification/overview).

This will ensure that you don't have to do custom preprocessing. But if you wish to stick to Densenet you can [add metadata](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata) to a TFLite model and build a [custom TFLite preprocessing pipeline](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/lite_support)